# Google LeaderBoard is not working when application is published on play store

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have implemented Google LeaderBoard in my android application. It is working fine when it is not published (testing mode) but it is showing "application is incorrectly configured".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a case of using the Debug Key during development, but then using a different Key for production.

If you are using Eclipse, and run as "some.android.app" using the steps that are normally shown in setting up the application (tutorials I've seen online), I would bet that many setup the app to run using the Debug Key.  (or some default Debug Key)

When you compiled your app to upload, did you use the same Key that is used to debug?  (if you try to install it to your device after build, if you get the error that the package doesn't match, then it's a different key)

Comment: yes, it was SHA1 key mismatch . earlier i was using sh1 of my debug.keystore and created the leaderboard using that key, but when i signed it from Signing key sh1 code for key was different. that is why my leaderboard was not working

Comment: i have same problem,  what is the solution ? i have found sha1 key from logcat and putted in google console.